# Limit in differential calculus

Tags: limits, derivatives

Find the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x+\sin^2(2x)}{2x^2-2\tan 3x}$$

I've tried using L'hopital rule, but I didn't get the right answer. Pls I need your help.

Comment: What did you get instead of the right answer?

Comment: Note close to 0, $\tan x\approx x$ and $\sin x\approx x$

Comment: Also how did you apply L’Hopitals rule, we need to see your attempt

Comment: The way I did it,
I've knew I'm not correct

Comment: @TehRod: You shouldn't use $\approx$, which doesn't correspond to a mathematical concept.

Comment: @Bernard what would be the correct symbol?

Comment: `\sim` ($\sim$) has to be used for equivalence of functions. ‘Approximately equal to’ is a physicist concept.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use standard limits.
We know $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.
So dividing each term in your limit by $x$, we get:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\tan x}{x}+\frac{2\sin(2x)}{2x}sin2x}{2x-6\frac{\tan 3x}{3x}}$$
Using standard limits above, we get in the numerator $1+0$ and the denominator is $-6$.

Comment: thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

Use *equivalents*:

$\tan x\sim_0 x$, $\sin 2x\sim_0 2x$, hence $\sin^2 2x\sim_0 4x^2$, so $\tan x+\sin^22x\sim_0\tan x\sim_0x$.

Similarly, $2x^2-2\tan 3x\sim_0 -6x$, and finally
$$\frac{\tan x+\sin^22x}{2x^2-2\tan 3x}\sim_0 \frac x{-6x}=-\frac{1}{6}.$$

Comment: @SxS: Thanks for correcting my typo!